# XSLT to generate sequential numbers which can be reset

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="01-25-2011" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="Pro 11.0v3"/>
    <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="Export to Ledes" NAME="StateFarmLedes1998b.fp7" RECORDS="27" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a"/>
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="date of bill" TYPE="DATE"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Invoice #" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Company Name" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    </METADATA>
    <RESULTSET FOUND="25">
        <ROW MODID="25" RECORDID="54">
            <COL>
                <DATA>20110707</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>2949801</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Foo</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="25" RECORDID="54">
            <COL>
                <DATA>20110707</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>2949802</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Bar</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
    </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

For the above XML, how would you write an XSLT transform which generates a pipe-delimited output, with a sequential "line item" count for each line item? The line item count should reset to 1 every time the invoice number changes.

Comment: `<xsl:number>` with a `count` xpath expression based on the preceding siblings?  http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_number.asp

Comment: @Mike an XSL I could test out would be terrific. How would you reset the number when the invoice number changes?

Comment: @Sam - could you give an example of the desired output for the xml above?

Comment: @Sam, is the invoice number the second `<COL>` per `<ROW>`.  If so, I think I'd need to know what is being processed when the expression appears so I can craft an Xpath expression to identify the prior siblings of the containing ROW.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but the best non simple xslt i've ever seen came with the source code to Kathleen Dollard's Code Generation.Net (http://www.apress.com/9781590591376)  If you want to see some examples of how to do some complicated stuff with xml/xslt check out her stuff.  Though she just provides the xslt you'll need a good reference for the language syntax to understand it like http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Probably XSLT 2.0 grouping would come in handy... is 2.0 available to you? I'm waiting with @Jason for the sample desired output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two complete solutions (XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0). Explanations are also provided. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:x="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">

 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/x:RESULTSET/x:ROW"
   group-adjacent="x:COL[2]/x:DATA">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:ROW">
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "string-join((xs:string(position()), x:COL/x:DATA), ',')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (essentially the provided one but added one more row to make it interesting):

```
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="01-25-2011" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="Pro 11.0v3"/>
    <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="Export to Ledes" NAME="StateFarmLedes1998b.fp7" RECORDS="27" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a"/>
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="date of bill" TYPE="DATE"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Invoice #" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Company Name" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    </METADATA>
    <RESULTSET FOUND="25">
        <ROW MODID="25" RECORDID="54">
            <COL>
                <DATA>20110707</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>2949801</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Foo</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="25" RECORDID="54">
            <COL>
                <DATA>20110707</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>2949801</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Foo</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="25" RECORDID="54">
            <COL>
                <DATA>20110707</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>2949802</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Bar</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
    </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
1,20110707,2949801,Foo
2,20110707,2949801,Foo
1,20110707,2949802,Bar
```

**Explanation**:

Use of **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group)** with the `group-adjacent` attribute.

**II. XSLT 1.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
 >
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing"
      match="x:ROW"
      use="generate-id(
            preceding-sibling::x:ROW
              [x:COL[2]/x:DATA
              =
               current()/x:COL[2]/x:DATA
              and
               not(preceding-sibling::x:ROW/x:COL[2]/x:DATA
                  =
                   current()/x:COL[2]/x:DATA
                  )
               ]
               [1]
                        )"
 />

 <xsl:template match=
  "x:ROW[not(x:COL[2]/x:DATA
            =
            preceding-sibling::x:ROW/x:COL[2]/x:DATA
            )
        ]
  ">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
       select=".|key('kFollowing',generate-id())"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:ROW" mode="group">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('&#xA;',position())"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="x:COL/x:DATA">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',.)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (shown above), the same correct result is produced:**

```
1,20110707,2949801,Foo
2,20110707,2949801,Foo
1,20110707,2949802,Bar
```

**Explanation**:

1. We use a template that matches every "head of group" `x:ROW` element.
2. We have specified a key which indexes any `x:ROW` in a group by the `generate-id()` of the "head of the group". This is convenient to specify easily the whole group and to apply templates on its elements (in mode "group").

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I'll need to use the XSLT 1.0 for my solution, but can appreciate how much cleaner the 2.0 is.

Comment: +1 - figured out what the OP was saying, without sample output.